# Configure Nginx to serve Wordpress or Angular app depending on route on the same EC2 under same domain name

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, amazon-ec2, routing

My goal is to serve a Wordpress site for my static pages for routes such as `/about-us` and `/contact` and then serve my bundled Angular application for the `/login/`, `/signup/`, and the user auth guarded routes.

I've configured nginx to serve my Wordpress site, however, when I try to access the `/login/` page, where the user will be served the Angular app, I'm not able to correctly re-write the web root folder and the server response is always a default nginx 404.

How do I properly overwrite the web root folder to point to the `index.html` of the Angular code base? I know I've misused the root directive in the last `location` block below.

- Wordpress index.php location = `/var/www/wordpress`
- Angular index.html location = `/var/www/dist/my-app`

My nginx configuration:

```
server {
  listen 80 default_server; 
  listen [::]:80 default_server; 

  root /var/www/wordpress; 
  index index.html index.php;

  server_name www.example.com example.com;

  if ($http_x_forwarded_proto = 'http'){
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
  }

  ### STATIC PAGE ROUTES ###

  location = / {
    # Wordpress site log files
    error_log /var/log/nginx/wordpress-error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/wordpress-access.log;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
  }

  # following by a bunch of other Wordpress routes ...

  location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    include fastcgi_params;
    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
  }

  ### PORTAL ROUTES ###

  location = /login/ {
    # Portal error logs
    error_log /var/log/nginx/portal-error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/portal-access.log;
    root /var/www/dist/my-app;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html

  }

  # would be other Angular routes ...

}
```

When navigating to `www.example.com/login/` with the configuration above I will get the following error in my nginx logs:

```
...
2019/05/07 20:42:14 [error] 3311#3311: *1280 open() "/var/www/wordpress/index.html" failed (2: No such file or directory),
...
```

Comment: `/login` != `/login/`

Comment: @womble Thank you for pointing that out. I should have been more clear. The `/login/` route does have a trailing slash. I've updated the question above.

Comment: The answer, then, will be in the nginx debug logs.

Answer (score 0):

I came to the answer with the help of the following:

- The error/access logs of nginx - @wombie
- [This stack overflow answer which explains the difference between the root and alias very well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10631933/nginx-static-file-serving-confusion-with-root-alias)
- official nginx documentation

I was able to achieve my goal by updating the last location block to serve the Angular application from the `/app/` route and directed nginx to `index.html` via `alias` instead of the `root` directive.

Updated Angular `location` block:

```
location ^~/app/ {
  # Portal log files
  error_log /var/log/nginx/portal-error.log;
  access_log /var/log/nginx/portal-access.log;
  alias /var/www/dist/may-app/;
  try_files $uri$args $uri$args/ /index.html =404; 
}
```